# Stegnography - hide text file within another text file in c#.net

Tags: c#

I have already seen solution for hiding text files or messages within Image or audio files..
but i want solution for hiding text file within another text files (.txt, .doc, .pdf).

can somebody help for this??

Comment: Not likely that a piece of software can merge 2 texts without it being obvious... And hiding it as a resource in doc/pdf isn't Steganography.

Comment: What is the solution you are talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steganography is based on slightly changing data to "hide" some other set of data within these changes. That's why an image with steganography is slightly different than the original. You can't notice if if you don't know it's there, but the fact is you saved the data as changes within color information of pixels.

.txt file is nothing else than a big hunk of characters. If you tried to somehow change the data to hide something in it, it would result in unreadable text. If you change the color of a pixel from 215 Red to 217 Red, you won't really notice. But changing A to F or Ł is quite noticable.

So no, I don't believe it can be done. At least not with .txt files.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @stonehead that at the end of the day if you put something in the file someone can find it, but there are a few tricks out their that may prove to be viable options.

Since most users are not living in their command prompt the most straight forward approach is to misrepresent the file to the GUI. This is a pretty handy trick for this.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-hide-data-in-a-secret-text-file-compartment/

If you are storing data in a pdf you should have very little problems. I would use PdfClown. Not to get too into it but you will want to read up about the structure of a pdf. With clown pdf you could store an asset inside with no connection to the presentation layer. Given the complexity of pdf files i will almost bet no one will be looking in, i would base64encode the chunk to have it blend in with images and other data it would be difficult for someone to find it by just opening up the file.

Be For Warned ClownPDF C# library is not for the faint of heart and it will help to have some java experience because a lot of their docs are for java.

Hope these options help.